# Docker compose - get rid of port from URL

Tags: url, docker-compose, port

I'am using following docker docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
    restart: on-failure
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

I am on Ubuntu and when I run it everything works fine. Then I can access my wordpress site from address localhost:8081.

That is my issue because for my work I need to have URL address without the port. At best to use some host name.

Is there a way how to work with docker to achieve that?

I have already unsuccessfully tried to do it by follow:

1. I have added line into file /etc/hosts `127.0.0.1  mysite.com`
2. I stopped apache2 to free port 80 `sudo service apache2 stop`
3. Then I set up my docker-compose.yaml file to expose wordpress to port 80 and run in.
4. backward verification: `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` and yes! Wordpress image is running on port 80.

Then when I try to go on localhost or mysite.com I'm immediately redirected to localhost:8000 and browser shows me that page is not found. What the hell?

I'm getting frustrated since I really need to have an address without port. I will be glad for whatever advice on how to achieve this.

Comment: I tried the same and it works perfect. Could it be a browser issue? If you use Chrome most surely is. Can you try with a different browser anyway?

Comment: Man you made my day! Chrome somehow cached redirection to port:8000! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I'll add it as an answer if anybody needs it. It happened to me quite a few times as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of behaviour you describe could be due to the browser having already cached this redirect in a previous session. Try using a different browser making sure it doesn't do any redirect.